# Add tooltip programmatically on asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code on my project. 
string="my string"

how i show this string on a button as a tool-tip. I want this to do programmatically. I want this to do in my code not the design.

i do my codings in asp.net with c# language

Comment: pls mark my answer if it helps for others to easily find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to add the `tooltip programmatically`

just get the id of the button

```
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

in your code behind:

```
//do some code to retrieve data from database and store it to this variable
String tooltip = "some text"; 

button1.ToolTip = tooltip;
```

Comment: I want to show the tooltip from my data which was get from a database.so i have data as strings on my code.so i need to show that strings on my tootltip.They are dynamicaly data.so can be changed.In my example i want to pass the "my string" to the tooltip but i want it without typing "my string".How can i do this?

Comment: How sample showing WinForm control will help OP with WebForms???